# Use card views as buttons

Tags: c#, android, android-cardview

On the home screen of my app i have a list of card views that i want to use as buttons to switch to their related fragment.

i want to do it similar to this instead of writing a onclick method for every card.

```html
private void BottomNavigation_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
            {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                
    
                switch (e.Item.ItemId)
                {
                    case Resource.Id.menu_home:
                        fragment = homeFragment;
                        break;
    
                    case Resource.Id.menu_favourites:
                        fragment = favFragment;
                        break;
    
                    case Resource.Id.menu_more:
                        fragment = moreFragment;
                        break;
                }
    
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTx = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.container, fragment);
                fragmentTx.Commit();
    
    
            }
```

I am doing this inside the home fragment and my cardviews are the paceCard, wattsCard and weightadjustCard. So how can i implement this for my cards?

Comment: please provide more details

Comment: theres not more i can add i want to use a similar onlcick method but for cardviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
public void onClickCardView(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.YOUR_ID:
        //statement
        break;
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.YOUR_ID:
        //statement
        break;
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.YOUR_ID:
        //statement
        break;
    }
}
```

and in your xml give all the card onClick:
like this

```
android:onClick="onClickCardView";
```

Comment: Only for android java :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare every CardView from your XML in java activity and put on them OnClickListener.

```
CardView cview1,cview2;
cview1=findViewById(R.id.cardViewOne);
cview1.setOnClickListener(......){
......}
```

Comment: I tagged that i use c# not java