# Is there a way to write a same onclick function for multiple controls?

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

I have came across a problem where i have multiple text view that should have the same onclick function. I can obviously write multiple onclick but i want an optimized code.

For example i have textviews of color red and othe textviews of color blue and i want all red to have same onclick and all blue to have a same onclick function different than red.

Is there a way to achieve this in android java?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52391122/6541643 see my answer

Comment: You can use jakewarthon butterknife

Answer (score 1):

declare your click event in a variable from type `View.OnClickListener` and then assign it to your textviews like this:

```
View.OnClickListener eventVar = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //do what you need
    }
};

textview1.setOnClickListener(eventVar);
textview2.setOnClickListener(eventVar);
textview3.setOnClickListener(eventVar);
textview4.setOnClickListener(eventVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id for red colour and another id for blue. And write a switch statement, if as below

```
switch (id)
      case 0:
        runAmethod();
        break;
      case 1:
        runAnotherMethod():
      break;
default:
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

First, create common public method for getting `TextView` click,

```
public void onTextViewClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.VIEW_ID:
        case R.id.VIEW_ID:
        case R.id.VIEW_ID:
            // Performs action for Blue Text View
            break;
        case R.id.VIEW_ID:
        case R.id.VIEW_ID:
            // Performs action for Red Text View
            break;
    }
}
```

Then, in your xml write `TextView onClick` like this,

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:onClick="onTextViewClick"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Write a common function for your all the color textview like

        private void clickOfRedTextView(){
        // your code.
        }

Now implement your activity or fragment with OnClickListener listener and pass the on click
    textviewred1.setOnClickListener(this);
    textviewred2.setOnClickListener(this);
    // so on ... 

In the override method of onclick you can have a switch case with view id as follow.
        public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.textviewred1:
                    case R.id.textviewred2:
                    so on.... 
                    // your function you want to call will come here. 
                   clickOfRedTextView();
                  break;
               }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simplest way:

Define your onClick in your xml file for your red type textviews and blue type textviews like this.

```
<TextView
    //other attributes...
    android:onClick="redTextViewMethod"/>
<TextView
    //other attributes...
    android:onClick="blueTextViewMethod"/>
```

And then define the redTextViewMethod method in your corresponding Java file like this

```
private void redTextViewMethod() {
    //your code
}
private void blueTextViewMethod() {
    //your code
}
```